# In Python, why is "sum([int(digit) for digit in str(n)" faster than "sum(int(digit) for digit in str(n))"?

Tags: python, string, loops

I was wondering about it:

```
> %timeit sum([int(digit) for digit in str(n)])
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 us per loop

> %timeit sum(int(digit) for digit in str(n))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.04 us per loop
```

Comment: What's `n`? Surely it cannot be very big. The overhead of calling the generator repeatedly will exceed the efficiency gain of not constructing the full list. Try a bigger list.

Comment: @nneonneo, with n='1234567890'*100 list wins, generator lose. How much bigger n must be?

Comment: transfer of one big object is faster then transporting many of small.